# Sakila schema showing NULL values for all tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Question solved! Turns out I need to import data after import schema.

---

Thanks for the comments guys! I've edited the question so its clearer-

I've just installed Mysql(8.0.19),mysql workbench(8.0) and sakila schema.

When I open up the workbench sakila does not sit in the schema panel so what I did is server > data import > import from self-contained file and imported sakila-schema.sql

After this,when I try to view table (every table under sakila schema) it shows Null and Action output says 0 rows returned.

Comment: What do you mean by "imported sakila on workbench", because you don't need to import this database, you just need to connect to your MySql server.

Which version of mysql and which version of Workbench do you use?

On which table do you make your Select ?

Comment: If you simply imported the schema then there would be no data. Check the .sql file and import schema and data.